# Is readFileSync() during initialization of a Node.js web app a bad approach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

There are a few static HTML-snippet files that I conditionally include in web pages that my Node app serves. I am thinking of having a cache map for these snippets, which I would include at the top of my Express's app.js file:

```
var cache = Object.create(null);
cache['404'] = fs.readFileSync('path/to/404.html');
cache['weekend'] = fs.readFileSync('path/to/weekend.html');
```

This code runs during initialization (i.e. whenever my Node app is (re)started). I wonder if using `readFileSync()` in this context is a bad approach.

---

For comparison, the analogous async approach:

```
var cache = Object.create(null);
fs.readFile('path/to/404.html', function (err, data) {
    cache['404'] = data;
});
fs.readFile('path/to/weekend.html', function (err, data) {
    cache['weekend'] = data;
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure so I won't submit an answer, but I believe that it's probably fine to do this...node.js likes to keep operations asynchronous to avoid delays when processing requests, but this is during startup before any requests get processed. Yes it will delay startup some number of miliseconds, but you probably don't want to be processing requests without those cache entries defined anyway...

Comment: BTW why are you doing Object.create(null) instead of just {}  - I thought Object.create(null) just created a regular empty object?

Comment: @MattBrowne It's a common approach to create an object that doesn't inherit anything - that's what I want here since I'm defining a simple key-to-value map. `{}` would work just as fine, but I find it cool that I can explicitly "disable" the prototype link when I don't need it. In the web browser environment, my approach has its benefits since some browsers may have bugs regarding using objects as maps, e.g. "toString" bug in old versions of IE.

Comment: Use async functions whenever you can. Node == async.

Comment: i agree that it's not bad ... but why not make it async and start listening in a callback? it won't hurt at all!

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto The callback pattern is just so tedious. See the code comparison in my question above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a long-running program, performing a synchronous request on startup is fine. The problem with a synchronous request is it will block the *entire* application. While your individual requests will suffer if they have to wait an extra 0.1 seconds for a response, your whole application will almost certainly not suffer if it takes an extra 0.1 second to start up. (I'm assuming your file isn't "huge").

To put another way: the only benefit of async is that there is other stuff that can be happening while the IO blocking call takes place. If this is your entire program:

```
readFileAsync(file, function() {
    startListeningForRequests();
}
```

Then it's equivalent to reading sync. However, the async version may be more maintainable if you need to read 1000 files on startup - you certainly would want that to happen in parallel. But in my practical experience as a web developer, that's unlikely, so sync is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Performing synchronous tasks before your server(s) start listening is fine because you're not blocking requests at that point.